# MongoDB (Node JS), how to correctly add calculated fields to a query result, where the calculated field uses a passed variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with feeds. The documents are structured something like this:

```
{
  _id: '123',
  title: 'my title',
  openedBy: ['321', '432', '543'] // ID of users
}
```

Then I have users:

```
{
  _id '321',
  friends: ['432'] // ID of users
}
```

What I would like to accomplish is to get the number of friends that has opened the feeds fetched by the user. I do this now with a mapReduce, passing the friends of the user fetching the feeds. I do not think I am doing it correctly as I reduce by only returning the emit itself and I have to convert the result back to a normal query result on the finalizer:

```
    db.collection(collectionName).mapReduce(function () {
        var openedByFriendsLength = 0;
        for (var x = 0; x < friends.length; x++) {
            if (this.openedBy.indexOf(friends[x]) >= 0) {
                openedByFriendsLength++;
            }
        }

        emit(this._id, {
            title: this.title,
            openedByLength: this.openedBy.length,
            openedByFriendsLength: openedByFriendsLength
        });
    }, function (key, emits) {
        return emits[0];
    }, {
        out: 'getFeeds',
        scope: {
            friends: user.friends
        },
    }, function (err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function (err, feeds) {
            // Convert the _id / value to a normal find result
            var resultFeeds = [];
            for (var x = 0; x < feeds.length; x++) {
                resultFeeds.push(feeds[x].value);
                resultFeeds[resultFeeds.length - 1]._id = feeds[x]._id;
            }
            callback(err, resultFeeds);
        });
    });
```

I have looked at aggregation, but I can not quite figure out how to do the same thing. Or is the structure of the documents here all wrong?

Thanks for any reply!

Answer (score 1):

You ask how to do the calculation using the aggregation framework. In general the aggregation framework performs better than map-reduce. You can find documentation on the Aggregation Framework here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/.

I understand that the calculation you want is, given a user, to find all feeds where that user is contained in the openedBy array, and then find the number of distinct friends of that user that are contained in those openedBy arrays. Do I have that correct?

Aggregation, like map-reduce, only operates on one collection at a time, so the first step is to obtain the list of friends for the user from the users collection, for example:

```
friends = db.users.findOne({_id:user}).friends
```

Then we can perform the following aggregation on the feeds collection to do the calculation:

```
db.feeds.aggregate([
    {$match: {openedBy: user}},
    {$unwind: '$openedBy'},
    {$match: {openedBy: {$in: friends}}},
    {$group: {_id: '$openedBy'}},
    {$group: {_id: 0, count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

The aggregate command specifies a list of processing steps that work much like a Unix pipeline, passing streams of documents from one stage of the pipeline to the next.

- The first first step in the pipeline, $match, takes as input all documents in the collection and selects only those where the user is contained in the openedBy array.
- The second step, $unwind, takes each input document and produces multiple output documents, one for each member of the openedBy array; each output document contains an openedBy field whose value is a single user. These will be users that opened the same feeds as the given user.  This step will allow later steps of the pipeline to perform aggregation operations on the indivdual values of the openedBy array.
- The third step, $match, filters those documents to pass only the ones where the openedBy user is a friend of the given user. However a given friend may be represented more than once in this stream, so aggregation will be needed to eliminate the duplicates.
- The fourth step, $group, performs an aggregation, generating one output document for each value of the openedBy field. This will be the set of unique friends, without duplication, of the given user who have opened a feed that the user opened. The _id field will be the friend user id.
- The final step, another $group, counts the number of documents generated by the preceding step. It outputs a single document, with an _id of 0 (you could use any value you want here), and with a count field that contains the final count that you wished to calculate, for example:

  { "result" : [ { "_id" : 0, "count" : 2 } ], "ok" : 1 }

I hope this answer is helpful! Let me know if you have further questions.

Bruce